# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined React Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to push some data through using an array to a grandchild class,
What I have is an array of id, summary, details which im using id for the key, summary is like a header, and details is hidden till you click the summary.

FAQ.js page

```
import React from "react";
import Accordions from '../components/Parts/Accordions';

let AccData = [
   {
     id: 1,
     summary: 'What Loans Do You Provide?',
     details: 'We lend £200 to £3,000 and have repayment terms from 6 
     months, 12 months, 15 months, 18 months or 24 months. You are welcome 
     to apply for a loan of any amount, however your approval will be 
     dependent on credit and affordability checks.',},
  {
     id: 2,
     summary: 'What Loan Terms Do You Offer?',
     details: 'You can borrow between £200 and £400 over a 6 month term. You 
     can borrow between £401 and £850 over a 12 month term. You can borrow 
     between £851 and £1,500 over a 15 month term. You can borrow between 
     £1,501 and £2,000 over a 18 month term, and you can borrow between 
     £2,001 and £3,000 over a 24 month term.'},
  {
     id: 3,
     summary: 'Can I Apply For A Loan?',
     details: 'To be eligible to apply for a loan, you must be at least 18 
     years old, a UK resident and have a UK bank account and debit card. You 
     must also have a net income of at least £700 per month, and be able to 
     comfortably afford the loan repayments.'
  }];

  export default class FAQ extends React.Component {
    render() {

      const hrStyle = {
         lineHeight:"10px",
         margin:"0",
         backgroundColor:"#3ba6f2",
         color:"#3ba6f2",
         border: "solid 2px #3ba6f2",
         width:"100%",
      }

      return (
    <div>
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <h4>The Basics</h4>
            <Accordions AccData={this.props.AccData}/>

        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
 }
```

Accordions.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Accordion from './Accordion';

export default class Accordions extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.props.AccData.map((summ)=> {
                    return <Accordion summ={summ} key={summ.id} />
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Accordion.js

```
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
    active: {
        display: 'inherit',
    },
    inactive: {
        display: 'none',
    }
};

export default class Accordion extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            active: false
        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }

    toggle(){
        this.setState({
            active: !this.state.active
        });
    }

    render(){

        const stateStyle = this.state.active ? styles.active : styles.inactive;

        const hand = {
            cursor:"pointer",
        }

        return (
            <li>
                <p onClick={this.toggle} style={hand}>
                    {this.state.active ? "▼" : "►"} {this.props.summ.summary}
                </p>
                <p style={stateStyle}>
                    {this.props.summ.details}
                </p>
            </li>
        )
    }
}
```

Sorry For messy code i just really don't know why map is undefined i followed a tutorial except from renaming things

Comment: Immediately inside of render: `console.log(this.props.AccData);` map is undefined because AccData is never assigned.

Comment: @mkaatman how do i assign it then im fairly new to react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is `AccData` need to be sent to child component like this. And `AccData={this.props.AccData}` should be `AccData={AccData}`

```
 return (
    <div>
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <h4>The Basics</h4>
            <Accordions AccData={AccData}/>

        </div>
    </div>
    );
```

Comment: @andywilson if this fixed it - mark it as the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your FAQ.js, `AccData` is just a local variable, it's not a memeber of `this.props`.

Change

```
<Accordions AccData={this.props.AccData}/>
```

... into

```
<Accordions AccData={AccData}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
return (
<div>
    <div className="container">
        <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <h4>The Basics</h4>
        <Accordions AccData={AccData}/>

    </div>
</div>
);
```

You define `AccData` in the `FAQs.js` page so just pass them in normally.  They'll be in scope since you defined it outside of your class.  You're getting undefined because `this.props.AccData` does not exist in your `FAQs.js` file.  It will, however, exist in `Accordions.js` since you're passing it down as a prop.